# In What Assembly is System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper Defined?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, t4

I'm trying to build a simple C# template for some EF 6.0 stuff.  I created the template in the same project that defines all of the Entity Framework objects.  However, I seem unable to use some of the types that can be found just fine in the Entity generator, specifically, `TypeMapper`.

Here is the top of my Entity generator T4 file:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#>
<#@  output extension=".cs"#>
<#
const string inputFile = @"EpicCloudDB.edmx";
#>
<#@ include file="EdmxEnumFixer.t4" #>
<#
var textTransform = DynamicTextTransformation.Create(this);
var code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);
var ef = new MetadataTools(this);
var typeMapper = new TypeMapper(code, ef, textTransform.Errors);
var fileManager = EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(this);
var itemCollection = new EdmMetadataLoader(textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors).CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
var codeStringGenerator = new CodeStringGenerator(code, typeMapper, ef);
#>
```

Nothing crazy going on here.  However, if I create a template and paste that directly into it (same project) it fails to find the following types:

1. TypeMapper
2. CodeStringGenerator
3. EdmMetadataLoader

I am in need of the TypeMapper only, but I don't understand why the same template code doesn't work in a fresh template, but runs just fine in the default EF file.

These classes are not easy to find documentation on either.  I figure if I can just find which assembly defines `TypeMapper` I can add the reference manually and worry about the general weirdness later, but that has proven more difficult than I expected.

So how can I get this type imported into my template?  I'll grep through the EF 6 source while I wait for an answer here.

Comment: You didn't look in EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude?  Should be defined in there.

Comment: @Will: I did, it's not. If they were the code would work. And like I said, you can copy the same exact template code above, which works in the EF entity generator, into a new template and it fails.

Comment: @Will: [Here is the definition](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/ModelConfiguration/Mappers/TypeMapper.cs)

Comment: Yeah, was taking a peek.  Nothing in there.  Freaky...

Comment: @Will: I know, it makes no sense to me.  The dumb stuff always takes the most time...

Comment: Well... that's the Mono version... Are you using the mono version?  And, well, maybe you should just turn on fusion logging and search those for what EF assemblies are being loaded.  You can then decompile them and look yourself.  A pain in the butt, but it may be your only option...

Comment: @Will: Geez, I didn't even notice that.  It's the only form of documentation I could find. No, no mono.

Comment: Got no answer.  Fusion log it :/

Comment: @Will: Just tried that.  I manually added references to _all_ of the DLL's that the working version pulls in (even though most are already brought in by the ttinclude.)  No luck. Where in the crap is this mystical class defined?  Yeesh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be defined in the very same .tt file - around line 320.

Comment: ...holy crap you're right.  I knew I was going to feel stupid after this was answered...